# Invalid object name 'TableName'

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am a newbie in sql server and I was unable to resolve this issue. I have been searching for 2 days and I am completely lost.

This is the error I am getting when the page is loaded.

> Invalid object name 'TableName'
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object
>   name 'TableName'.

This is my code

```
private void BindListView()
{
    string ConString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection SConnection = new SqlConnection(ConString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand SCommand = new SqlCommand())
        {
            SCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TableName";
            SCommand.Connection = SConnection;
            using (SqlDataAdapter SDAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SCommand))
            {
                DataTable DTable = new DataTable();
                SDAdapter.Fill(DTable);      //This is the line where i am getting error
                NewsList.DataSource = DTable;
                NewsList.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my connection string.

```
<add name="ApplicationServices"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

The code is working fine on my computer with localhost. But when the website is hosted its not working.

On the host I found this connection string for the database, and I replaced the above with this in `web.config` file. But I am getting the error above

```
<add name="ApplicationServices"
     connectionString="Data Source=.\MSSQLSERVER2014;Integrated Security=True;User ID=user;Password=password;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I think the problem is connecting with the database and I don't know what to do.

Please help

Comment: The exception is telling you it can't find a table called "TableName" in your database.

Comment: Does the 'TableName' table exist in both the localhost database and the hosted database?

Comment: Is the DB you are trying to connect to on the same server?

Comment: The database connection succeeded but the query failed.  Check the server and database in the connection string and make sure the table exists in that database.  Also, schema-qualify object names to avoid ambiguity (e.g. `dbo.TableName`).

Comment: You're connecting just fine.  You wouldn't get that error if there was an issue connecting to the database, which means your connection string is fine.  Your query is the issue.

Comment: Assuming the table actually exists (which I doubt), it's recommendable to use functional names for objects. Instead of "TableName" use "Products" (or whatever is in the table), instead of "aspnetdb" for the database name, use "WebshopXXX" (or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

Your local host connection string is pointing to the a file database that you will need to either attach or move to the server so you can utilize that database file.

My suggestion would be to attach that database file to your local sqlexpress server and then you can move the database to the hosting server when you need to publish.

Comment: Also in your Web.config file for the on the host computer you are missing the following: "AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf"